# Insert timestamp with milliseconds to Postgres table with PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table, like so:

```
create table test
    (
        time_stamp timestamp
    );
```

I want to generate a string with PHP that will insert the current time, with milliseconds (or microseconds) into the table.

Based on some other research, I've tried inserting the results of:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', time())
```

But I'm only getting seconds. Any ideas?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/time   it returns seconds. If you want milliseconds, then http://php.net/microtime but note that `date()` expects seconds as input anyways, so if you pass in a microtime, you're going to end up with some far-future time string, because it'll 1000000x bigger than what date()'s expecting.

Comment: Why not do it in SQL?  `insert into test (time_stamp) values (current_timestamp)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or u can use date:

```
list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime()); 
$usec = str_replace("0.", ".", $usec);
print date('H:i:s', $sec) . $usec;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had assumed there was an easy way to do this in PHP, but apparently there's not. Here's the solution:

```
function get_time() {
    $time = microtime(true);
    $micro_time = sprintf("%06d", ($time - floor($time)) * 1e6);
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s.', $time).$micro_time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using date_create [1] from class datetime [2]

```
$dt1 = date_create();
echo $dt1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');

2021-09-09 11:12:04.292321
```

[1]
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create

[2]
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php